# event.target.value returning an object in React Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, frontend, react-hooks

I am doing this simple thing which sets the state to whatever I type. The onChange function is behaving weird.
**What I want my state to be :** 
item = { task: }

I wonder what I am doing wrong. Attaching my code.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function TodoForm(props) {

    const [ item , setItem ] = useState({});
    const changeHandler = (event) => {
        let value = {task: event.target.value}
        console.log(value['task']); 
         /**********************************
          CONSOLE OUTPUT as I type: 
          *[object Object]s
          *[object Object]d
          *[object Object]f
         ***********************************/
        setItem(value);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={(event) => submitHandler(event)}> 
                <input value={item} onChange={changeHandler}/>
                <button> save </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Pretty sure I am doing something very silly here.
Getting the below output

Comment: `item` is an object that contains the value, but you are sending it as the prop `value` which expects the string value, not an object.

Answer (score 4):

Since `item` is an object, the value of the input should be `item.task`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function TodoForm(props) {

    const [ item , setItem ] = useState({});
    const changeHandler = (event) => {
        let value = {task: event.target.value}
        setItem(value);
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={(event) => submitHandler(event)}> 
                <input value={item.task} onChange={changeHandler}/>
                <button> save </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Oh damn. Thank you so much.